# Как отследить пользователя между двумя доменами?

Tags: php, javascript, get, google-analytics

В Google Analytics (для примера, вопрос общий) существует [междоменное отслеживание](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342):

> Для отслеживания сеансов Google Analytics при каждом обращении
>   регистрирует идентификатор клиента и сохраняет его в файле cookie.
>   Доступ к такому файлу может получить только сайт, который находится в
>   том же домене, что и файл. При междоменном отслеживании сеансов нужно
>   передавать идентификатор клиента из одного домена в другой. **Для
>   этого в коде отслеживания Google Analytics используется связывание,
>   которое позволяет исходному домену добавлять идентификатор клиента в
>   параметры URL, из которого целевой домен может его считать.**

Я правильно понимаю что GA просто добавляет параметр `?q=` ко всем ссылкам на сайте, а если просто открыть другой домен вбив его в адресную строку, то GA уже ничего не передаст? Или там какая то более сложная технология?

Comment: Не знаю зачем такие сложности они делают, но если GA ставит свою куку в браузер, то появляется возможность отслеживать пользователя на сайтах где так же установлена GA. Хотя, может им куки запретили ставить :)

Comment: @Visman Как вы прочитаете куку с другого домена? Вопрос в том чтобы отследить пользователя между двумя разными доменами. Т.е. узнать что это один и тот же пользователь.

Comment: Для GA на страницу подгружается js с их сайта, а раз так, то этот сайт может ставить куки для себя, в свой домен. И на любом сайте с GA для аналитики будет доступны их собственные куки.

Comment: @Visman Может смысл в том, что GA никаких данных не отправляет в ответ на запросы и не нагружает пользователя лишним трафиком?

Comment: Тест показал, что GA не ставит куки в свой домен. Скрипт js прописывает куки в домен сайта, который открыл пользователь. Так что если такое поведения аналитики стандартно, то действительно при удалении идентификатора клиента из get параметров, отслеживания пользователя не будет.

Comment: Если есть под рукой два домена настроенных на отслеживание, проведите опыт. Откройте один сайт, а на втором сайте удалите куки. Потом перейдите по ссылке на второй сайт, но в ссылке удалите идентификатор пользователя и после этого сверьте идентификаторы из кук GA на обоих сайтах.